# Highlight individual bar in ggplot2 bar chart that corresponds to an individual's specific PDF report

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

Apologies for the bad title, I wasn't sure how to best convey what my problem is.

To give some context, I want to create a personalized scorecard for each provider in our organization using Rmarkdown. I already figured out how to create an individual PDF for each provider ; however, I want to have a simple bar chart on everyone's report with the provider's position highlighted so that they can compare themselves to their peers. Below is what I have so far:

First I created the dataset:

```
############################## Create dataset and export #####################################
df = data.frame(
  "Provider" = c("A","B","C","D"),
  "Measure" = c(1.2,0.8,1.7,0.4)
)
write.csv(df, "pathway/df.csv")
```

Next I created an Rmarkdown file named "TEST" that calls in the dataset and includes a graph

````
###################### Create Rmarkdown file named "TEST" ####################################
---
  output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
df <- read.csv("pathway/df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
name <- df$Provider[i]

Dear `r name`,

This is your personalized scorecard.

```{r} 
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Provider, -Measure), y=Measure,
                        fill = factor(ifelse(Provider == "A", "You","Your Peers"))), 
           stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Provider", values=c("steelblue","lightgrey"))
````

Finally I created an R file with the for-loop to create as many PDFs as there are providers

```
################ Run R file with loop to make separate PDFs per Provider #####################
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

#Read data
df <- read.csv("pathway/df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Create loop
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  rmarkdown::render(input = "pathway/TEST.Rmd",
                    output_format = "pdf_document",
                    output_file = paste("handout_", i, ".pdf", sep=''),
                    output_dir = "pathway/folder/")
}
```

In the code above for the ggplot2 graph I manually coded provider "A" to be highlighted in blue and the rest of the providers grey, but we have over 30 providers and I don't want to manually code for each one. If there is some way for Rmarkdown to automatically highlight each provider in blue and the rest grey for each of their PDF reports that would be amazing. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your code, so I give the correct files here.

## The RMD file:

you have to submit parameters, in your case *i*. You also did this in `name <- df$Provider[i]` but *i* was not given. Also you have to load `ggplot2` and set your chunks ob the right positions.

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  i: 1
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
name <- df$Provider[i]
```

Dear `r name`,

This is your personalized scorecard.

```{r} 
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Provider, -Measure), y=Measure,
                    fill = factor(ifelse(Provider == df$Provider[i], "You","Your Peers"))), 
       stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Provider", values=c("steelblue","lightgrey"))
```
````

## The R file loop

Here you also have to submit the parameter too.

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

#Read data
df <- read.csv("pathway/df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Create loop
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  rmarkdown::render(input = "pathway/TEST.Rmd",
                    output_format = "pdf_document",
                    output_file = paste("handout_", i, ".pdf", sep=''),
                    output_dir = "pathway/folder/",
                    params = list(i = i)))}
```